# Reunir dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Bom dia.

Para aplicar um algoritmo de balanceamento, separo um dataframe em X e y:

```
X = df.drop(['covid_longa'], axis=1)
y = df['covid_longa']
```

Balanceamento:

```
from collections import Counter
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler 

print('Original dataset shape %s' % Counter(y))

rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=42)
X_res, y_res = rus.fit_resample(X, y)

print('Resampled dataset shape %s' % Counter(y_res))
```

Original dataset shape Counter({0: 1268444, 1: 150239})
Resampled dataset shape Counter({0: 150239, 1: 150239})

Como "remontar" X_res e y_res em um novo dataframe df, que então estará balanceado?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
```

Gerando uma data set aleatório para teste - 30% da classe 0, 70% da classe 1

```
x, y = make_classification(n_features=5, n_samples=15, weights=[0.3, 0.7])
```

Fazendo o undersampling

```
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=42)
under_x, under_y = rus.fit_resample(x, y)
```

Criando nomes para as features no dataframe

```
nome_coluna = [f'fetaure_{a}' for a in range(5)]
nome_y = ['target']
```

Voce tem 2 arrays numpy, precisa converter

```
under_x = pd.DataFrame(under_x, columns=nome_coluna)
under_y = pd.DataFrame(under_y, columns=nome_y)
```

Concatenando os dataframes

```
df = pd.concat([under_x, under_y], axis=1)
df
```

|  | fetaure_0 | fetaure_1 | fetaure_2 | fetaure_3 | fetaure_4 | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -0.832487 | 0.101922 | -0.063718 | -0.271529 | -0.493319 | 0 |
| 1 | -1.795138 | 0.269398 | -0.103635 | 0.439472 | -0.985433 | 0 |
| 2 | -1.588549 | 0.452757 | 0.054160 | -0.279992 | -0.533582 | 0 |
| 3 | -0.599718 | 0.513594 | 0.253624 | 1.966745 | 0.339578 | 0 |
| 4 | -0.166711 | -0.282595 | -0.218949 | -1.717649 | -0.577190 | 0 |
| 5 | 0.708866 | 0.290095 | 0.310717 | 0.030758 | 1.015103 | 1 |
| 6 | 0.283073 | 0.394922 | 0.313986 | -0.810678 | 0.845986 | 1 |
| 7 | -0.192897 | 0.187109 | 0.096489 | -0.332368 | 0.143822 | 1 |
| 8 | 2.281291 | -1.580715 | -0.710976 | -0.135707 | -0.702879 | 1 |
| 9 | 1.499596 | -0.995987 | -0.438036 | 1.399350 | -0.394004 | 1 |

Comment: Obrigado, lmonferrari. Tentei assim: df = under_x.join(under_y) e parece que funcionou.